# Rhino python code generation

Tags: python, rhino3d

I just started learning using Python with Rhino. I study architecture and have a very basic background with programming in general. Last year I had to deal with some geometry creation using javascript with three.js.

I have found, of course, multiple information online about Python commands, where everything is explained so well, but lacking almost any use of a programming-language background, this is not enough for me.

Is there a way I can draw some curves, basic cylinder/box/etc in Rhino and get the python code for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am an architect too, I first learned programming (and Python) with this very good tutorial book by David Rutten:
http://www.rhino3d.com/download/ironpython/5.0/rhinopython101 It is made for creating geometry in Rhino3D. It will also help you understand NURBS curves and surfaces better. In addition to that you can find short code examples in the [RhinoPython documentation](http://developer.rhino3d.com/api/RhinoScriptSyntax/win/) . For example here is one about creating a cylinder: http://developer.rhino3d.com/api/RhinoScriptSyntax/win/#heading-AddCylinder

For creating and manipulating geometry in Rhino3D I would really stick to the samples on [Rhino3D](http://developer.rhino3d.com/guides/rhinopython/what-is-rhinopython/) (and [Grasshpper3D](http://www.grasshopper3d.com/forum/categories/vb-c-and-python-coding/listForCategory)) related websites.
There are many general Phyton tutorials out there but most of them are about other more common topics of software development and are probabaly confusing if you just want to use Python within Rhino3D for geometry scripting. For example you can savely ignore anything about object oriented programming and classes if you just write rather short scripts for yourself.